# Visual Studio 2015 Express and Visual SourceSafe 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I tried following this instruction. but I still cannot get sourceSafe to appear in the available plug in selection. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Bb166193.aspx

I have two computer. Computer A and Computer B. 
Computer A has Visual Studio 2013 Premium and Visual SourceSafe 2005. 
and I can see the plug in in the selection 
like this 
[image]

Computer B has visual studio 2015 Express and Visual SourceSafe 2005. And this is all I see
[image]

Can you please help me how to add this plug in? Thank you

Comment: VSS is a discontinued source control, and VS2015 is a newly released piece of software.  What makes you think that VS2015 would have a VSS plugin available immediately following release? (Or at all?)

Comment: why does your question reference VS13 and VS15, but you've tagged VS10 and VS12?

Comment: I am pretty sure if I install visual studio 2015 premium, I will get the option no?

Comment: I fixed my problems I was installing Visual studio 2015 for desktop and the option is not there. But when I install Visual Studio Community 2015. the option is available Now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I install Visual Studio Community 2015 (make sure you use vs_community.exe) and SourceSafe option will be available.

I was using vs_Desktop.exe previously.

Make sure to select and download the community edition instead of the visual studio express for desktop

Answer (score 0):

There is patch for Visual SourceSafe that once installed lets you see the SourceSafe plugin in the Visual Studio Tools|Source Control plugin list here it is

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=291

Hope this helps